# I am getting an error "Declaration of class TForm5 is missing or incorrect" whenever I use the Form Designer

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi CE v11.3.

Whenever I try to access the Form Designer, I get this error message:

> Error in module msl_main: Declaration of class TForm5 is missing or incorrect.

I *think* this is because the object in the repository is broken. How do I fix this? I cannot find `TForm5` in the registry. I have reinstalled Delphi but the problem persists.
A imple test project: Click on the form and getthe eror.
Can someone tell me how to fix this?

````
    
    interface
    
    uses
      Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
      Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;
    
    type
      TForm5 = class(TForm)
      private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;
    
    var
      Form5: TForm5;
    
    implementation
    
    {$R *.dfm}
    
    end.
    
    object Form5: TForm5
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'Form5'
      ClientHeight = 201
      ClientWidth = 447
      Color = clBtnFace
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clWindowText
      Font.Height = -11
      Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
      Font.Style = []
      OldCreateOrder = False
      PixelsPerInch = 96
      TextHeight = 13
    end ```
````

Comment: You have managed to corrupt your .pas or .dfm file. Use a text editor to fix these files.

Comment: If you would post your *.pas, I could tell you how to fix it.

Comment: What "reposirory" (presumably repository) do you think is broken? Why do you think `TForm5` would be in the "regiatry" (presumably registry)?

Comment: If you start a new VCL project do you still have problems?  Or delete all files except dpr pas and dfm and see if you still have a problem. Reload the project and see

Comment: Or load the pas file as a file if it loads it is a dpr problem

Comment: Since the form empty, I'd just close all files, go into the folder where the project lives, delete the files, and start over by creating a new VCL project. It's way simpler than tracking down a missing declaration, which is probably in your project file.